# Magento vs Opencart vs WooCommerce For AutoParts

Tags: php, magento, woocommerce, opencart, e-commerce

maybe its not related to this community. But I have big problem, I've build an auto-parts store on WooCommerce, The auto parts structure something like this: One Products belong to Thousands categories. Like 17" tire will work with thousands of vehicles. So when a product being viewed, wordpress get all categories/taxonomies. When user browse an archive, the thousands (categories/taxonomies) * 20 (products) were called, we can't ignore the vehicle models because its important. User search products from the car model. I've to move from WooCommerce. What will be better in my case.
PS: I want to develop like roughcountry.com, wheelmax.com, carid.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have fully eCommerce concept without many custom things which you require then you can go with either Magento or Opencart. Opencart is very lightweight eCommerce functionality. If you have limited categories, products, users then you can choose Opencart. They provide the best admin panel to easily manage. Opencart development cost is very low as compared to Magento. Magento is also a good option if you have to plan to big eCommerce functionality on your website. I will suggest you opencart is the best option now. If you have many custom functionality require then you have to choose any custom framework like codeignitor, zend etc

Comment: I want to develop like roughcountry.com, wheelmax.com, carid.com, can you please check it for me.

Comment: If you have similar like roughcountry.com, wheelmax.com, carid.com then go with Magento.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'll try :)

Answer (score -1):

You can still use woocommerce as your store platform as the other 2 solutions still operate on a product to category manner.

Use a plugin such as 'year make model' or YMM to list your auto parts by vehicle. 
As for tyres look for a plugin that would allow you to filter tyres based on rim size, tread with etc... Otherwise get one custom built.

But IMHO your on a platform that will suit your needs.

Comment: I've tried those plugins, But they can't match the requirements, as can read, I want to filter, the products with car model, not just want filters

Comment: Thats exactly what they allow you to do. If you add your car make a model you will only be shown products that suit your selection. You can then filter by category e.g. exhaust, tyres, engine etc.

Comment: Yes, they do, but the problem is, If I select all cars that fits to the wheel size, it would be thousands, but while loading products, WP get all models, so it takes so much time to load